# How to get the following reductions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am reading a textbook on number theory and encounter the following reduction steps. But I cannot understand why are them sound. Who can give me more detailed reductions?

Suppose $p_i$ are primes, then

(1) $(1-1/p_i)^{-1} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} 1/p_i^m$

(2) $-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\ell}\log(1-p_i^{-1})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\ell}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}(mp_i^m)^{-1}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For the first formula, use the fact that for $|r|<1$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n} = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

For the second formula, expand out the logarithm by noting that that the derivative of $\log (1 - x)$ is $(1-x)^{-1}$. To be more precise, you know that

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$$

If we let $x = 1/p$ we get

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^{n}}$$

Integrating both sides gives

$$\log(1 - \frac{1}{p}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-n)p^{n-1}}$$

If we consider the minus sign, then

$$ - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-n)p^{n-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)p^{n-1}} =  \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{mp^{m}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have still failed to work out the second formula. Would you please to give me a detailed reduction?

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much! I understand now.

Comment: @Pigmann My pleasure. Actually, I see that you have posted a number of questions on MSE without accepting them. We generally encourage users to accept answers to their questions because it gives useful feedback to those of us who answer questions.